# Among Kubernetes, OpenShift, Docker Swarm and Docker DataCenter deployment tools which all are having automatic rollback?

Tags: docker, openshift, kubernetes, devops, docker-swarm

Among Kubernetes, OpenShift, Docker Swarm and Docker DataCenter deployment tools which all are having automatic rollback in case of any failure happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of them have a sort of rollback mechanism built-in with commands available for you to control. However, these are not fully automated and you might have to do it manually. For Kubernetes, here is the related github [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23211) and another [issue](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1085) for Swarm. Docker DataCenter use Swarm already.

Rollback documentations I was able to find:

- Kubernetes: [Rolling Back a Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-back-a-deployment)
- Swarm: [Roll back to the previous version of a service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#roll-back-to-the-previous-version-of-a-service) (features `--update-delay`)
- OpenShift: [Rolling Back a Deployment](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/deployments.html#rolling-back-a-deployment)